# insert data into second table if insert into first table has been done successfully otherwise don't insert data

Tags: c#, sqlite

i have two tables in **Sqlite** i want if user inserted data into first table then a specific data be inserted into the second table but if insertion on the first table succeded and on  second table failed then data inserted into the first table must be removed , how to manage this in c# with sqlite ?
i mean is there any way in sqlite or sql to manage this??
here is the code i use in c# :

```
                queryString = string.Format(@"insert into customerHost values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')",
                "1", userID, hostPlan,  hostServiceDate, hostExpiresOn ,hostPrice);
            if (new dataAccess().insertQuery(queryString) == 1)// if data has been inserted into the first table successfully then insert into the second one
            {
                MessageBox.Show("good", "good");
                queryString = String.Format(@"insert into hostUpdate values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')",
                    Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), userID, hostServiceDate, hostExpiresOn);
                if (new dataAccess().insertQuery(queryString) != 1)//if data insertion into the second table failed then throw an errro....in fact data inserted into the first table must be removed
                    MessageBox.Show("some errors has been occured ", "error");
            }
```

Comment: how to user that ??

Comment: If only there were a way to [search for such things](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%23%5d%20transaction) ...

Answer (score -1):

you can use triggers in SQLite.
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Could you please include the relevant parts from your link in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can google about it easily.. i did and below is some part of the code which was found in the [first link](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitecsharp/trans/) given by google.

please note that below is just an example, below is the the complete answer and it is a must that you read the attached and may be few more articles on transactions in databases....

```
     string cs = "URI=file:test.db";        

    using (SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection(cs)) 
    {
        con.Open();

        using(SqliteTransaction tr = con.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (SqliteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {

                cmd.Transaction = tr;
                cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Friends";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

             ...............

             }

            tr.Commit();
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not complete; it does not even insert anything.